# npm ERR code ENOSELF when installing angular-notification-icons

Tags: angularjs, npm

I am trying to use this link as a reference to build a Notification system:

https://github.com/jacob-meacham/angular-notification-icons

First step is Running:

```
 npm install angular-notification-icons --save
```

I am not sure what path I need to run this? I try to run it in my project path but I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "angular-notification-icons" under a package
npm ERR! also called "angular-notification-icons". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing?
npm ERR!
```

Comment: what is your project name.

Comment: you should run this inside your project root path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem cause when name of project in **`package.json`** is similar with the name of **`npm`** module.

To solve please change project name in **`package.json`** to other.

example "angular-notification-icons-test"

```
{
  "name": "angular-notification-icons-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve",
      "build": "ng build",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  ...
}
```